# Robot Framework CSS attribute selector

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors, robotframework

The Selenium documentation for Get Element Attribute gives an example of:

```
${id}=  Get Element Attribute   css:h1  id
```

However, this selector doesn't function for me:

```
${VISIBILITY}=    Get Element Attribute    css:visibility    mySidebar
```

where the HTML is:

```
<div id="mySidebar">
```

and the attribute visibility is:

```
Style Attribute {
    z-index: 104;
    visibility: visible;
```

What is a functioning selector for this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that "visibility" is not an attribute on the WebElement, it is a component of the "style" attribute.

I think that if you get the style:

```
${STYLE}=    Get Element Attribute    css:style    mySidebar
```

you can then parse that to check visibility (sorry, it's been ages since I used Robot Framework, so I'll leave it to you how you do that)..

With that said, you didn't mention what you are doing with the visibility.  Perhaps it would be more helpful to use one of the visibility related keywords, like `Element Should Be Visible`?

Comment: Thanks - Element Should Be Visible seems (according to the documentation) to mean logically visible on the page, if not physically visible - which would be different for the sidebar I'm looking at.

Comment: so, have you tried to work directly with the style then?

Comment: Yes I have, the Get Element Attribute line is returning Get Element Attribute css:style discoveryPanel when using Log To Console.